# "Inconsistent Operand Constraints" with Inline ASM using GCC

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

Getting this error when trying to compile this source file using GCC:
https://github.com/wolf9466/cpuminer-multi/blob/master/cryptonight_aesni.c

"cryptonight_aesni.c:162:4: error: inconsistent operand constraints"

Specifically:

```
      uint64_t hi, lo;
 // hi,lo = 64bit x 64bit multiply of c[0] and b[0]

  __asm__("mulq %3\n\t"
      : "=d" (hi),
        "=a" (lo)
      : "%a" (c[0]),
        "rm" (b[0])
      : "cc" );
```

Very difficult to find out what this error even means, yet alone how to fix it

Comment: What processor are you targeting?

Comment: Intel 32 bit, filler

Comment: The instruction `mulq` in this code is an x86 64-bit instruction. All the parameters are 64-bit values and can't fit in 32-bit registers (when compiling for a 32-bit x86 platform)

Comment: Ah yes makes sense, installing mingw64 thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The instruction `mulq` in this code is an x86 64-bit instruction. All the parameters are 64-bit values and can't fit in 32-bit registers (when compiling for a 32-bit x86 platform)
                    – Michael Petch